# AppEngine Error Handling

Tags: google-app-engine

All,

Is there a way to error out/exit execution out of a handler? For instance, if the incoming request doesn't contain the correct headers we want to send a 400 and exit/close the connection. However, whenever we use `self.error(400)` or `self.response.set_status(400)` any other code after it executes anyway So, for example:

```
class MyPastaHandler(webapp2.Handler):
   def get():
      if not self.request.headers.get('My-Custom-Header'):
         self.error(400)
      ...
      [more code]
      self.response.out.write('{"success": "true"}')
```

When I submit a request w/o the said custom header, I get back a 400, but I also get the success json in the body of the response, which tells me that `self.error(400)` doesn't stop execution and neither does `self.response.set_status(400)`.

So, the question is, is it possible to literally error out of a handler?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, there is a simple way to exit after a 400 (or any custom error). As described by TheFluff in the AppEngine IRC channel, a simple, old-fashioned empty `return` after the self.error(400) will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

In webapp2 abort() is a shortcut to raise a HTTP exception: http://webapp-improved.appspot.com/guide/exceptions.html#abort